# Should I implement a failsafe for my ajax calls, or it is not necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I know it correctly, javascript is single threaded, which means, only one thing is being done at a same time. I am creating a full ajax webpage, where all the navigation is done, by sending data to the server, and rendering the result on the screen, with the help of javascript.

Let's take for example the following javascript:

```
$.post( "script.php", function( data ) {
  for (var z=0; z<data; z++) {
    console.log("B");
  }
});

$.post( "script.php", function( data ) {
  for (var z=0; z<data; z++) {
    console.log("C");
  }
});

var i=-1;
while (i<0) { 
/* I know that this is an infinite cycle, but let's just bear with this for the sake of my 
example, and let's pressume the browser would run this correctly, without lagging, crashing*/
  console.log("A");
}
```

Let's also presume that script.php generates a random number between 5-300, sleeps for that amount of seconds, and then echoes this number. How would the browser interpret this code? My logic says the following things, please correct me when and if I am wrong somewhere:

1. We don't know which post will finish sooner, because of the random number.
2. Javascript will first call for script.php file, afterwards, it will call once again for script.php file, and then it starts logging the letter A to the console.

What happens when one of the jQuery posts finish? Because of javascripts single threadedness, does the execution of the while cycle stops, and the script starts executing the callback of that post? What happens if the second post finishes when we are executing the callback from the first post? Does the callback of the first post stops, and javascript starts executing the second posts callback? Is it possible that at sometime of my script, I will see the following console.log message?

> A A B B B C C C C B A A

The reason of my question is: what if the user who is browsing my site, clicks on a link, and my javascript sends the request to the server, but BEFORE the response to the request arrives, the user clicks on a second link? Is it possible that the two responses get mixed? Or both the responses will be executed, but in order of their arrival?

Comment: Could someone please explain, why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote wasn't from me, and I don't think it was warranted, but I will note that the question is asked in a somewhat convoluted way given what it turns out you're actually trying to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask:

> What happens when one of the jQuery posts finish? Because of javascripts single threadedness, does the execution of the while cycle stops, and the script starts executing the callback of that post?

But in the example code you state:

> I know that this is an infinite cycle, but let's just bear with this for the sake of my 
>   example, and let's pressume the browser would run this correctly, without lagging, crashing

That statement makes it impossible to answer the question.

If we are allowed to not make that assumption and are allowed to explain exactly what happens in a real browser then we can answer that question.

So here goes:

### What happens when one of the jQuery posts finish?

It will never finish.

That's because the browser will never send the network packet.

That's because the while loop is running.

Why is that? It's got to do with how the event loop works. Here's a simple diagram of the event loop:

```
Event loop
    ┌──────────┐
    │          │
    │          │
    │          ▼
    │        (1) check if there's any new ───────▶ parse data
    │        data on the network                        │
    │          │                                        │
    │          ▼                                        │
    │        (2) check if we need to execute  ◀─────────┘
    │        any javascript ─────────────────────▶ execute
    │          │                                  javascript
    │          ▼                                        │
    │        (3) check if we need to ◀──────────────────┘
    │        redraw the page  ──────────────────▶ redraw page
    │          │                                        │
    │          │                                        │
    └────◀─────┴─────────────────◀──────────────────────┘
```

Your `while` loop causes the browser to be stuck in step (2) -- executing javascript.

The jQuery ajax function does not send an ajax request to your server. Instead it simply queues an ajax request in your browser's networking code.

The browser cannot do anything else while it's executing javascript. It cannot draw to the screen, it cannot send a network packet. That's because it's single threaded.

Once there is no more javascript to run (once your program ends) the browser finally re-enters the event loop and can execute graphics and networking code.

When the browser loops back to step (1) it finally sends the two ajax requests to the server. Then nothing happens for a long time (at least from the point of the CPU). During this time the browser doesn't use your CPU at all. If you look at your process manager you'll find the CPU usage is almost zero.

During this do-nothing time, since the browser is not busy, it is able to process user events such as mouse move and mouse clicks. The event loop doesn't loop all the time. When there really is nothing to do the event loop gets paused in step (1) waiting for any I/O.

When your server's packets finally arrives at the browser, it triggers an I/O event and it checks if there are any callbacks associated with the event. In this case it would detect that the network response has been associated with the callback from `jQuery.ajax`. Therefore it pulls that callback from the list of pending callbacks and enter step (2) again to execute the javascript.

When your callback function returns and there are no other callbacks that needs to run the browser will enter step (3) then go back to step (1) and wait for the second server response.

All this keeps running until there are no more pending callbacks.

---

Now, to answer your second question:

> The reason of my question is: what if the user who is browsing my site, clicks on a link, and my javascript sends the request to the server, but BEFORE the response to the request arrives, the user clicks on a second link? Is it possible that the two responses get mixed? Or both the responses will be executed, but in order of their arrival?

The two responses can finish in any order - not necessarily the order of arrival. But the two responses will never get mixed. That's because the callbacks are associated with the requests.

There is one edge case. The association is made using sockets. The two requests are sent on different sockets and the browser remembers which socket has which callback. But HTTP allows servers to handle more than one HTTP transaction per socket. This is called pipelining. If your server implements HTTP pipelining, it is never allowed to send responses out of order within a single socket (it still can if they are two separate sockets). But if your server implements buggy HTTP pipelining code, it's possible that the two requests will get mixed up.

For this reason browsers used to disable pipelining by default. But some advanced users (like me) used to turn it on. So in that one edge case it's possible for the responses to be mixed up (caused me a world of hurt trying to debug it).

Comment: The requests will not get mixed up, but if the requests are fetching content and putting them in the DOM, they can be placed out of the order in which they were initiated. This is exacerbated if the response handlers are overwriting areas of the page with what was fetched. I believe this is the crux of the question.

Comment: @JAAulde: That is a possible race condition but it's more of a design pattern issue rather than an architectural issue. The crux of the question is how events are processed while other code are running. The answer is they're not processed at all until nothing is running. Once you understand this everything else is much simpler to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

They can absolutely arrive in the wrong order. Block the UI to trigger the second ajax call or just kill the second call before it starts if the first hasn't returned.

Networking is a pain, and if you open chrome dev tools, you can see that each request starts and stops with random fluctuations in transfer time. Sometimes time to first byte explodes for some odd reason. The web is weird.

Even loading this page there are requests that start first and finish second. If ajax calls are triggered by the user, you need to handle them. If you're doing a series of ajax calls programmatically, there are libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to make that easier.

[image: timeline of network requests]

Comment: I also tought about blocking the ajax calls if the first did not finish yet, but I don't think this is really user friendly. What if the user selects a contact person whose data he/she wants to view, but by mistakes clicks on another contact. He/she realizes the error, and quickly clicks on the correct contact, but if it is blocked, the user must wait until the response from the first ajax arrives. My other tought was, to throw away data from responses that are not needed anymore. (continued)

Comment: I would assign an UID for each ajax call, and when the respones comes back, check if that UID is still needed, or not, and if not, just throw away the response. This is more user friendly IMO, but it weighes heavy on the server, as each ajax call arrives to the server, and the server then processes the data for each click.

Comment: If the case is selecting from a list for details on the right, I would probably switch from an updating-the-ui model to a data-event model, kind of like what ember/angular try to do. When you get an ajax response, setup a cache of local data. When you click on a name, mark the currently selected item. Now each sidebar is generated from a particular selection as opposed to the ajax response. Set data instead of the DOM, essentially, and the problem ~mostly goes away. May be time to invest in a JS framework.

Comment: Blocking is not a good answer given we're talking about async operations. If blocking were a good idea, the OP could use a synchronous request in the first place, so no new code would need to be written to perform the blocking. As an async methodology was chosen, we should not break the concept.

Comment: @JAALude "Block the UI" by disabling form elements, for example, or not updating the dom when a new selection has been made. Yeah, never actually serialize ajax requests. That's madness.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but I believe any form of blocking violates the purpose of the asycn methodologies. It should use very, _very_ rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of asking the question is a little confusing which may explain some of the long answers addressing other points, and none of them yet answering what you're wanting. The crux of your question (as evidenced by your followup comments to other answers) is about users clicking content links and having content show up in the wrong order. Worst case of this would be an earlier request finishing after a later request and overwriting content on screen.

While one can stop taking in new requests until the current one has finished (blocking), it violates the purposes of async methodologies.

Ideally one would track requests and cancel them when a new one comes in which should supersede a previous one.

Below is an example of a simplified method for aliasing `$.ajax` in order to add tracking for existing requests.

```
/*
 * Declare a function that will be used to load content and track previous requests
 *
 * Notice we're not assigning it to the function that is being defined on the same line,
 * ather that function is executing immeidately and its return value, a function, will
 * be assigned.
 */
var loadContent = (function () {
    // Privatized variable which will hold the last made request
    var last_request;

    /*
     * The actual definition of loadContent (notice it is being returned)
     * Takes a URL and options (just like $.ajax). it looks to see if there was a previous request and whether it has finished.
     * If there is a prev request, and it hasn't finished, it is aborted.
     *
     * @param string url Where to make the request
     * @param object opts optional $.ajax options
     */
    return function (url, opts) {
        // Look for previous request. If there is one, and it isn't finished, abort it
        if (last_request && last_request.ready_state !== 4) {
            last_request.abort();
        }

        // Make the new request, storing it into our tracked last request
        last_request = $.ajax(url, opts || {});

        // Return the (new) last request for use outside use of promises, etc if desired
        return last_request;
    };
}());
```

Any request made through this function will cancel any previously made request that came through it. Note that you can still use `$.ajax` or other aliases to it in parallel to this. You would route all AJAX calls through this which should cause previously made, similar calls to abort, meanwhile making other calls to `$.ajax` in other areas of code that are not associated with the particular functionality that needs to supersede.

Here is an example of what I mean by that last part:

Given this HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/aboutus.html" class="content-link">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services.html" class="content-link">Services</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content">
        Main Site Content
    </div>

    <div id="feedContent">
        Perhaps something loading dynamically from a feed
    </div>
</div>
```

This JS would let content links run through the code which cancels previous requests, while something unrelated loads other content and doesn't interfere (or be interfered with):

```
$(function () {
    var content_area = $('#content'),
        feed_area = $('#feedContent'),
        // Our previously defined function, minus all the comments
        loadContent = (function () {
            var last_request;

            return function (url, opts) {
                if (last_request && last_request.ready_state !== 4) {
                    last_request.abort();
                }

                last_request = $.ajax(url, opts || {});

                return last_request;
            };
        }());

    // Route main content links through the loadContent method which aborts previous, unfinished requests
    $('a.content-link').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        loadContent($(this).attr('href'), {
            success: function (content) {
                content_area.html(content);
            }
        });
    });

    // Directly use $.ajax to load something unrelated
    $.ajax('/feed-url', {
        success: function (content) {
            feed_area.html(content);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems that there are some people here on StackOverflow, who randomly downvote anything, just for the fun of it. If at least StackOverflow would let us see, who made the downvote, it would be much more usefull, because these "downvoters" would quickly disappear from the community. As for the answer, thanks for the effort(gave it +1 already), and I will try to implement this also in to my AjaxCall class:)